# Statusbar background color doesn't change

Tags: ios, swift, background-color, statusbar

I am developing an iOS app. It consists of several viewcontrollers. There are some viewcontrollers for registering and logging in, and other main viewcontrollers for using original feature.

I hid statusbar on the viewcontrollers for registering and loggin in. That works well like below screenshot.

[image]

But I wanted to display statusbar after registering. So I wrote some codes.

In AppDeletegate.swift, and other viewcontrollers(used after registering)

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x7F7EBC)
```

However, it didn't work. If I register my account, and then according to code like this,

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "App", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "appStoryboard")
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

moving on main viewcontrollers, there is no statusbar like below image.

[image]

But there is the worse thing that makes me confused.
If I restart the app, I can see the statusbar that has the color that I wanted to see.
(If I finished registering process, When I restart the app, it moves straight to main viewcontrollers that consists of Tab Bar controller )

[image]

I tried to use almost all the codes on internet to change the color of statusbar, but it couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.
I added a code in a ViewController.
That made statusbar empty.